# How to set awk/grep output as enviromental variable?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, cron

Maybe not the best command for it but it works:

```
ip address show | awk '{print $2}' | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" | grep "10.*"
```

This outputs the IP that starst with 10.* i.e:
10.71.179.60

What I would like is that this IP is set as a permanent enviromental variable (I think its called) - as $privateip

So a cronjob would every minute run a bash script that has this in it:

```
ip address show | awk '{print $2}' | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" | grep "10.*"
```

Send the IP, which changes from time to time, from the command into:

```
export PRIVATEIP=*the output/IP of the above command*
```

So whenever I run $PRIVATEIP in a script, the IP will be fetched :). This needs to be permanent.

Does anyone knows how to do this?!

### **EDIT EDIT EDIT**

Timur Shtatland solved this:

```
export PRIVATEIP=`ip address show | awk '{print $2}' | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" | grep "10.*"`
```

But not I have another problem :D. This worked perfectly when running manually in terminal. But when I run it as a cronjob, like:

```
* * * * * export PRIVATEIP=`ip address show | awk '{print $2}' | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" | grep "10.*"`
```

or

```
* * * * * bash /path/to/script.sh
```

which contains

```
#!/bin/bash
export PRIVATEIP=`ip address show | awk '{print $2}' | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" | grep "10.*"`
```

... It does not work. Any idea?!

Comment: There should be no need to pipe awk through to grep or vice versa. You can combine the grep into the awk statement,

Comment: That's not how environment variable work.  If you run that cron job, then the script will happily run and assign PRIVATEIP in its environment.  Then the script terminates, and its environment is discarded.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that helped my slow brain. But how should I do to have it available permanently in ALL enviroments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export PRIVATEIP=$( ip address show | awk '{print $2}' | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" | grep "10.*" )
```

or

```
export PRIVATEIP=`ip address show | awk '{print $2}' | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" | grep "10.*"`
```

Comment: Damn it. So it worked when running it manually but not when having it as a cronjob either the command by itself OR bash /path/to/ipscript.sh?

Any idea?

Comment: You need to specify the full path in most cases, or set PATH at the top of crontab file. This is because the cronjob environment is rather minimal and uses only a subset of the PATH as you see it in an interactive shell, by default.

Comment: `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/scriptfolder`

Is this it? I put this in my script.sh. Added /home/scriptfolder at the end of the PATH-line. And then calling it via cronjob `/bin/bash /home/scriptfolder/script.sh` Still not working. Sorry im a newbie.

Comment: So are all of the executables in this PATH: `ip`, `awk`, `grep`? And what do you mean by "not worked" - what error message did you get?

Comment: Haha! I am 100% lost. I found this via Google. By your question I understand the purpose of PATH, i think. This script is only using `ip, awk and grep` which as far as i know are all available in `/usr/bin`. My script is available in `/home/scriptfolder/script.sh`... So shouldnt a simple "PATH=/usr/bin:/home/scriptfolder" below `#!/bin/bash` do the trick? Whats not working is the cronjob running & exporting into $PRIVATEIP. I only get it to work manually in terminal.

Comment: If you have no error messages when saving the crontab or when the job is run (in your mail), then the cron job may have executed fine. Do not expect this single EXPORT command to do much else though, if it is successful. It does not modify your environment other than in the cron job **itself** (which exits after the EXPORT command is finished). For lasting changes to your env, you need modify ~/.bashrc or any of the other dot files, as you need. Feel free to ask this in a separate question to get a better answer.

Comment: Oh is that so.I thought that, when I run $PRIVATEIP in terminal just to make sure the cronjob have actually exported the value, it does not show the IP. So this would only affect cronjob, and not for "everyone, everywhere"?

Comment: You are right, submitted a new question instead. Thank you very much for your patience